# Access FormArray reference in ng-template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I have a component that displays some form fields depending of a given object. Normally, the component is called in a loop by a parent component that gives a new object each time, then, the child component shows the right element depending on the type.

**[Here is the StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-c1vgys)**

But sometimes, the element could be an **iterable**, a repeatable element (in case of a `FormArray`). I have the following code:

```js
<div [formGroup]="form">

  <ng-template #formTmpl
               let-field="field"
               let-index="index">
    <pre>index: {{ index }}</pre>
    <label [attr.for]="!!question.iterable ? question.key + index : question.key">{{ question.label }}</label>

    <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">

      <div [attr.formArrayName]="!!question.iterable ? question.key : null">
        <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'"
               [class]="isValid ? config.validClass : config.invalidClass"
               [formControlName]="!!question.iterable ? index : question.key"
               [placeholder]="question.placeholder"
               [id]="!!question.iterable ? question.key + index : question.key"
               [type]="question['type']">

        <select [id]="question.key"
                *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'"
                [class]="isValid ? config.validClass : config.invalidClass"
                [formControlName]="question.key">
          <option value=""
                  disabled
                  *ngIf="!!question.placeholder"
                  selected>{{ question.placeholder }}</option>
          <option *ngFor="let opt of question['options']"
                  [value]="opt.key">{{ opt.value }}</option>
        </select>

        <textarea *ngSwitchCase="'textarea'"
                  [formControlName]="question.key"
                  [id]="question.key"
                  [class]="isValid ? config.validClass : config.invalidClass"
                  [cols]="question['cols']"
                  [rows]="question['rows']"
                  [maxlength]="question['maxlength']"
                  [minlength]="question['minlength']"
                  [placeholder]="question.placeholder"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="errorMessage"
         *ngIf="!isValid">{{ question.label }} is required</div>

  </ng-template>

  <div *ngIf="question.iterable; else formTmpl">
    val {{questionArray.value | json}}
    <div *ngFor="let field of questionArray.controls; let i=index; last as isLast">
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="formTmpl"
                    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{field: field, index: i}"></ng-container>
      <button *ngIf="question.iterable && isLast"
              type="button"
              (click)="addItem(question)">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

for the moment, I'm testing the repeatability of an element on `inputs` **only**.

So for one element, it works well, but it can't get the reference to the optional directive: `[attr.formArrayName]="!!question.iterable ? question.key : null"`

If try the following (putting the input directly in the `ng-container`, without calling the `ng-template`:

```js
  <div *ngIf="question.iterable; else formTmpl">
    val {{questionArray.value | json}}
    <div *ngFor="let field of questionArray.controls; let i=index; last as isLast">
      <input [class]="isValid ? config.validClass : config.invalidClass"
             [formControlName]="i"
             [placeholder]="question.placeholder"
             [id]="question.key"
             [type]="question['type']">
      <button *ngIf="question.iterable && isLast"
              type="button"
              (click)="addItem(question)">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the input field shows well, and the value of the Form is well bind to it.

What's strange is that the `formControlName` of each field inside the `ng-template` have their value bind well to the form.

The error I got at the form init is:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute
    at _throwError (vendor.js:74769)
    at setUpControl (vendor.js:74593)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (vendor.js:78338)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (vendor.js:78989)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (vendor.js:78912)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.js:59547)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.js:70213)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:70152)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:71174)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (vendor.js:71117)
```

Then, if I add a new element to the formArray, the new element appears but isn't bind, and this new errors shows:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: '1'
    at _throwError (vendor.js:74769)
    at setUpControl (vendor.js:74593)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (vendor.js:78338)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (vendor.js:78989)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (vendor.js:78912)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.js:59547)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.js:70213)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:70152)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:71174)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (vendor.js:71117)
```

So how can I make the field taking in account the `formArrayName` property ?

You can see below the attribute is present in the markup (but I thought it were `ng-reflect-name` normally), but it's not working anyway:

[image]

As final example, here's a screenshot of the form (notice the indexes above each repeatable inputs):

[image]

**[Here is the StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-c1vgys)**

Comment: your code is hard to read and there are things difficult to figure out. what is the purpose of `let-field="field"`? where is `question` and `questionArray` defined? what is the structure of `form` in `[formGroup]="form"`? it would be great if you could provide a reproducible example in stackbliz.

Comment: You're right @ysf, sorry! There is some debug code I let in by mistake. I edited the post with a GitHub repo. Please make sure you're on the `feature/add-iterable-field-option` branch. ;)

Comment: I finally ended up adding a StackBlitz @ysf :https://stackblitz.com/github/zzminoxv

Comment: stackblitz link is not working. i was able to reproduce the error using github repo. honestly, i used to think that i had my share of reactive forms until i saw your code :) yesterday i had a bit struggle to understand what is going on in your code. today i am gonna take a look at it again. i ll let you know if i can come up with anything.

Comment: @ysf I'm so sorry, here's the right link ;) https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-c1vgys Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think `[attr.formArrayName]="!!question.iterable ? question.key : null"` binding doesn't work because it is performed as [attribute binding instead of input binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property)

however, when we convert it to input binding new errors occur for non-FormArray questions in your use case.

so, using good-old `formControl` directive instead of `formControlName` solves the problem.

```
[formControl]="form.get(question.iterable ? [question.key, index] : question.key)"
```

also with this approach you don't need `[attr.formArrayName]="!!question.iterable ? question.key : null"` binding anymore

here is a working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-c1vgys-5zjdj7)

Comment: `[formControl]="form.get(question.iterable ? [question.key, index] : question.key)"`

Comment: @yurzui thanks for the great tip. i updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you, I didn't know it was possible to call `formControl` directly instead of classic inputs (`formControlName`, `formArrayName`, etc). That's really, really interesting! I even might make a getter to retrieve the `formControl` directly! ;) Thank you again!